# Problem booting Ubuntu OS in multiboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have windows 8.1 and ubuntu 18. I installed ubuntu 20. However when i start my laptop, I see the GRUB menu with only ubuntu 18 and windows options. To boot up ubuntu 20, I need to use the GRUB CLI.I now want to uninstall the ubuntu 18 (I have taken the necessary data I need from it)

I assume GRUB needs to be fixed/configured to use Ubuntu 20 and Windows 8.1 and then I can safely delete the ubuntu 18 partitions? Or is there a better way?

PS - my ubuntu 18 doesn't start via the GUI mode, I can just access it via the Console mode

Ubuntu 18 here refers to 18.04.5 whereas ubuntu 20 refers to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances (or cloud use) do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18, nor Ubuntu 20, and Ubuntu *yy* releases are different products to the *yy.mm* releases.

Comment: Have you tried booting the 20.04 install and then running `sudo update-grub`? if everything is set up okay and all are using the same BIOS/UEFI boot mode, both Windows and 18.04 will be added to the 20.04 boot menu. Then you can remove 18.04.

Comment: I ran sudo update-grub on both the ubuntus. But while booting, it shows the grub menu from the ubuntu 18 (SInce it is at the top) Is it safe now to uninstall ubuntu 18?

Comment: First confirm that you are booting from 20.04's boot loader. perhaps change the name of boot/grub/grub.cfg in the 18.04 install to xxxgrub.cfg and confirm 20.04 still boots. I would expect 20.04 to come first in the boot menu.